# AS3: Socket's connection time: 1 second, too slow, isn't it?

Tags: apache-flex, performance, sockets, connection

I'd like to know what the average time is to connect a socket in Flash.
My application uses a socket that requests information to a server (in localhost). 1 connection/close for every request.

Hence, I measured the time between a `socket.connect()` call and an Event.CONNECTION reception and it was around 1100 ms. I think is too slow.

Besides, I cannot connect, close and connect again. I have to create a new socket for each connection, a bit strange, isn't it?

The server accepts multiple connections and it's under C#.

Answer (score 1):

Check to makes sure it's not a server problem.  I have used Sockets a few times and yes, 1 second is slow. It should be much faster unless there's a handshaking issue between Flex and your server.

You can definitely connect, close and connect again, as long as the socket is actually disconnected (the 'close' function is async, listen for disconnected event) since just like the original handshake to connect, the socket needs to properly close with the server.

Comment: upppsss, I didn't remember that close() method was async!!! That answers why I couldn't reconnect (close() and connect() again). Big mistake... Thanks a lot!!!!!!

On the other hand, the flash socket really takes 1 second to connect to the server (I tested on two .NET servers), or at least, that's the time between "connect()" and the Event.COMPLETE reception. Maybe Flash Player does other things in background ..(check domain-across policy, the event flow and so on). I wonder if I'll be able to ask Adobe labs for this information...

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Two .NET servers made by you?  All I'm saying is debug the backend to check if it's not something back there that's causing the issue.  The Flash Player does check sandbox security, but it's extremely quick and should interrupt the connection process.  Again, I'm fairly certain it's not the socket since I've been using them quite a bit and haven't seen this behavior.  There has to be something else causing this problem.

Comment: Also, if you're going to say 'ups', why not actually do it?